# Ubuntu 20.04, ubuntu-drivers: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages (complaining about nvidia-driver-515)

Tags: drivers, apt, 20.04, nvidia, dell

When I'm running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` on my Ubuntu 20.04, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-515 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-515 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-515 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-515 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-515 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-515 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-515 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-515:i386 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (= 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It happens on my Laptop (Dell Inspiron 15 5510, with Ubuntu pre-installed by the manufacturer).
I tried a lot of stuff that others suggested to others around the web and none of it worked.
This is the output of `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia` (can't see 515 on the list although it's displayed on the "Software & Updates" UI, but not in use):

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64                   470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-470                       470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-450:amd64                460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                              amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-compute-460
ii  libnvidia-compute-470:amd64                470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-470:i386                 470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-470:amd64                 470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-470:i386                  470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-470:amd64                 470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-470:i386                  470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-470:amd64                  470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64                   470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-470:i386                    470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-470:amd64                     470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-470:i386                      470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64                   470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386                    470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-470                   470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-470                            470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-450                          460.91.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                              amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-driver-460
ii  nvidia-driver-460                          470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-driver-470
ii  nvidia-driver-470                          470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-470                   470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-470                   470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.16~0.20.04.2                                        all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.3                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-470                           470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  oem-fix-gfx-nvidia-ondemandmode            1.2                                                     all          Set the power ondemand mode by default
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18build1                                              all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470              470.129.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

*BTW, the initial issue that lead me to try upgrading the drivers is that sometimes my laptop isn't waking up after it's going to sleep and I have to restart (which is annoying).

---

-- Any help or idea would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually using `aptitude` to install the drivers solved it.
*As suggested on Nvidia's forums: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-ubuntu-drivers-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages-complaining-about-nvidia-driver-515/227587